# How to send html body and plain attachment with perl Net::SMTP

Tags: perl, smtp

besides there is Mime:Lite etc. I have no other possibility to use Net::SMTP.

I am trying to send an email containing html message part and also an attachment containing text. I guess something is not in the right order or mime format may be incorrect?

I can get the attachment with the content but no message in the email body is displayed:

```
 $smtp->data();
 $smtp->datasend("Subject: ".$self->{SUBJECT}."\n");
 $smtp->datasend("To: ".@{$self->{TO}}[0]."\n");
 $smtp->datasend("From: ".$self->{FROM}."\n");
 $smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
 $smtp->datasend("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"frontier\"\n");
 $smtp->datasend("\n--frontier\n");
 $smtp->datasend("Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\" \n");
 $smtp->datasend("<h3>".$self->{BODY}."<\/h3>");
 $smtp->datasend("\n");
 $smtp->datasend("--frontier\n");
 $smtp->datasend("Content-Type: application/text; name= traps.txt \n");
 $smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"traps.txt\"\n");
 $smtp->datasend("\n");
 $smtp->datasend($self->{BODY});
 $smtp->datasend("\n");
 $smtp->datasend("--frontier\n");
 $smtp->dataend();
 $smtp->quit;
```

Comment: The final boundary needs `--` at the end: `$smtp->datasend("--frontier--\n");`

Comment: I would like to understand why?

Comment: boundary markers are prepended by '--', and in the case of the last marker, it is also appended by '--'.  That's the definition of the MIME protocol!